# How can I get the name (string) of the users location using the facebook graph api?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can not figure out how to access data of anything that returns an object with type 'page' (hometown or location).
I read on another stackoverflow question that I needed to use the ' -> ' notation in order to access specific pieces of the object but that doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be great!

```
  $config = array(
    'appId' => '##############',
    'secret' => '#########################',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'] . "<br />";
        echo "Gender: : "  . $user_profile['gender'] . "<br />";
        echo "Birthday: " . $user_profile['birthday']. "<br />";
        echo "Religion: " . $user_profile['religion']. "<br />";
        echo "Hometown: " . $user_profile['hometown']->name. "<br />";
        echo "Location: " . $user_profile['location']->name. "<br />";

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "user_religion_politics,user_birthday"));
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "user_religion_politics,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location"));
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}

?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$user_profile['hometown']->name
$user_profile['location']->name
```

Use-

```
$user_profile['hometown']['name']
$user_profile['location']['name']
```